How do I override an abstract method with a generic return type?
I'm trying to write classes something like this:
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public abstract BaseInstance<BaseModel> CreateInstance();
}

public class SpecializedModel : BaseModel
{
    public override BaseInstance<BaseModel> CreateInstance()
    {
        return new SpecializedInstance<SpecializedModel>(this)
    }
}


public abstract class BaseInstance<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    protected BaseInstance(T model) { ///... }
}

public class SpecializedInstance<T> : BaseInstance<T> where T : SpecializedModel
{
    public SpecializedInstance(T model) : base(model) { //... }
}

I'm having a problem with the CreateInstance method in SpecializedModel. As it is, I get this error:

Cannot implicitly convert SpecializedInstance to BaseInstance

I tried changing the SpecializedInstance's return type to SpecializedInstance<SpecializedModel>, but then it says that the return type must be BaseInstance<BaseModel>. I tried making the SpecializedInstance class concrete, but it still gets the "cannot convert" error.
So is this even possible? The various specialized instance classes will need to be able to access the specialized properties of their models, and I'd rather not have to use casts for this.

This is a weekly question, in short, you cannot treat A<Derived> as a subclass of A<Base> unless A<Base> is a covariant interface. You can assign an object of type IDerived<CDerived> to a variable of type IBase<CBase>, still the interface has to be covariant. So play with covariant interfaces, not classes.

@Leonide — To start with, where is BaseInstance? You could would not compile also due to the line protected BaseInstance(T model) { /// ...  }, as the comment disables the closing bracket. Please try everything on your compiler before posting.
